# Laravel 5.1 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cartItems()

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have the following model and controller but it keeps throwing error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cartItems()
```

This is my model and controller:

```
 class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
       'user_id',
       'coupon_id',
    ];

    public function cartItems()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\CartItem');
    }

}


use App\Cart;
use App\CartItem;

class CartController extends Controller
{


    public function index()
    {

       $userId = Auth::user()->id;

       $cart =  Cart::where('user_id', '=', $userId); 

       $cartItems = $cart->cartItems()->get();

       //...some other stuff...

       return view('cart.index', compact('cartItems'));
    }

 }
```

Comment: Did you add "use App\Cart" or the model path in the top? try "App\Cart" instead of" Cart".

Comment: @paolo.basso99 yes I've used App\Cart but it throws the same error. I can't seem to find anything glaringly obvious that would throw this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call it as a function:

```
$cart =  Cart::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->first(); 
$cartItems = $cart->cartItems;
```

Laravel will take care of the rest, and get the items from the database.

Comment: already tried that, it doesn't work, gives error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$cartItems`

Comment: Check the updated answer, you need to select the first() entry to get a model instance